# は after adverbs

Tags: grammar, particle-は

I don' understand what it means/adds on these sentences, since there's an adverb before them and the particle can be omitted and it still makes sense

今**は**...しない

目の前でこんなに弱られたら誰だって少し**は**優しくなりますよ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 今{いま}**は**...しない
>
> 目{め}の前{まえ}でこんなに弱{よわ}られたら誰{だれ}だって少{すこ}し**は**優{やさ}しくなりますよ

This usage of 「は」 is for emphasizing the meaning of the preceding word.  It often implies a contrast as well.

> "I am not doing it *now*. (I might do it later on.)"
>
> "If a person became this weak before your very eyes, anyone would be a little bit more (if not by much) gentle."

「弱られたら」 is in the famous "suffering passive" form, meaning I had to use a different grammar around the verb in my translation to make any sense in English.

Comment: so the は emphasizes the "little" in the sense of "at least a little nicer" or a "little nicer at best"?

Comment: 弱られたら I understood it as "if you are (so=こんなに) weakened/troubled", is it difficult to translate it in English for native Jp speakers?

Comment: @YTKN 弱られたら doesn't mean "if you are weakened". 弱る is an **intransitive** verb, and 弱られる is its passive form. It's suffering passive (迷惑の受身), a kind of indirect passive (間接受身), just as 「子供に泣かれた」「雨に降られた」「妻に死なれた」

Comment: @Chocolate how would you translate it then so that it keeps the Japanese meaning as much as possible?

Comment: @YTKN  子供に泣かれた -> A child cried (and it bothered me), 雨に降られた -> It rained (and I got wet / it affected me in some way), 妻に死なれた -> My wife died (and I suffered)... but I don't know how to translate 目の前で弱られたら... "if (someone) becomes weak in front of my eyes (and I see it and feel sorry)", maybe?

Comment: @Chocolate could this suffering passive be a way to emphasize the whole sentence? since 目の前でこんなに弱られたら is followed by 誰だって少しは優しくなりますよ, the 誰だって少しは優しくなりますよis already kind of implying that the speaker is being a bit nicer because seeing the listener weak affects him and makes him feel bad/sorry (?) or is this passive 弱られたら the only construction possible for 弱る here?

Comment: @YTKN I can't be sure without context but... you could probably rephrase it 「目の前で(人が)こんなに弱(って)るのを見たら、誰だって...」"If you saw someone get so weak/troubled in front of your eyes, you'd.." The られ might be emphasizing the sentence..  「目の前で弱られたら..」 sounds to me like you're forced to see the person get weak/troubled..

Comment: @Chocolate context is from a manga, a girl lies on a guy's shoulder and asks him to let her stay like this for a bit since she's too nervous because they have to give a presentation, so he awkwardly pets her and she says he's being nicer than usual, so he says that line. Did that help a bit? By the way, if it's against the rules to comment here, we can move it to the chat. It's just that I've never heard of the suffering passive so it makes me curious...

Comment: @YTKN Yes, so I think it's like "If someone gets this weak in front of your eyes (and it affects you in some way.. in this case you have no choice but see it, you cannot ignore it, it inevitably makes you feel sorry, etc.) then you'd naturally be nicer, at least a little bit / even if not much"... If you'd like to know more about suffering/indirect passive, you're free to post this as a separate question.

Comment: @Chocolate yes, i'll do it in other occasion, thanks. just to finish this topic for real now, that sentence felt a bit distant/a little bit impolite/tsundere?, is it actually a normal reply in Japanese?

Comment: @YTKN 特に "distant" な感じもないですし、"impolite" って感じもないと思いますが。。。「（いつもは優しくない俺だけど、）今はこんな状況だから優しくなるのも当たり前じゃん」みたいな、いい訳か照れ隠しみたいな感じですかね・・？普段どんなキャラなのかわかんないけど。。。

Comment: @Chocolate So the は particle can be placed after quite anything, even after a temporal noun/adverb like in YKTN example, or after a typical adverb like in 少しは彼が言っている意味が分かる, with always the same function to "emphasize the meaning of the preceding word"?

Answer (score 1):

> 今は...しない

This implies "I won't do (something) now, but I might later." Without the は, there's no implying the "but I might later" part.

> ...少しは優しくなりますよ

To me this implies "will become a little bit kinder, but not necessarily a lot kinder, but definitely not unchanged or reduced in kindness level either". Without the は, there's no implying the "but not necessarily a lot kinder, but definitely not unchanged in kindness level either" part.

Open to feedback!